# Craft CMS website not loading CSS and JavaScript files

Tags: php, html, twig, content-management-system, craftcms

I cloned an existing Craft project from a Git repository and ran the `php craft setup` command to add my own database credentials and SECURITY_KEY in the .env file.

I'm running it on my local server using MAMP. The database port is set to 8889 and the server is pointing to the Craft project's ***web*** folder.

When I visit my localhost, the website does load and I can see all the images that load via the HTML. But it doesn't load the CSS or JavaScript. In the console, the link to CSS files shows **href=(unknown)**.

In the .twig templates, the links to CSS use siteUrl like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% includeCssFile siteUrl~'css/file.css' %}">
```

And JS files like this:

```
{% includeJsFile siteUrl~'js/file.js' %}
```

And this is what my .env file looks like:

```
# The environment Craft is currently running in ('dev', 'staging', 'production', etc.)
ENVIRONMENT="dev"

# The secure key Craft will use for hashing and encrypting data
SECURITY_KEY="myKey"

# The Data Source Name (“DSN”) that tells Craft how to connect to the database
DB_DSN="mysql:host=localhost;port=8888;dbname=db"

# The database username to connect with
DB_USER="user"

# The database password to connect with
DB_PASSWORD="user"

# The database schema that will be used (PostgreSQL only)
DB_SCHEMA=""

# The prefix that should be added to generated table names (only necessary if multiple things are sharing the same database)
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=""

DEFAULT_SITE_URL="http://localhost:8888/project/web/"
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

- Setup a Craft project from scratch using Composer
- Set the '***devMode***' to '**false**' in config/general.php
- Changed the **db port** to 3306
- Setup the database by logging into Craft's admin panel

None of the above worked. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See [documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/2.x/templating/includecssfile.html#parameters), path needs to be relative and the call shouldn't be inside a link element

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your method using for example:

```
{% includeJsFile siteUrl~'js/file.js' %}
```

It seems like the path isn't correctly. However, I think I got an appropriate solution for you:

1. Add variable(s) to your `.env` file.
2. Add those variables as aliases in the `general.php`
3. Use them in your templates.

To give you an example:

1. Add `YOUR_NAME="https://yoursite.com"` to the `.env` file.
2. Add the following to the `general.php` in your `config` folder:

```
'aliases' => [
   '@your_name' => getenv('YOUR_NAME')
],
```

3. Use the alias in the templates:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ alias('@your_name') }}/css/file.png">
```

*Extra tip: Those variables are also usable for configuring your volumes in Assets within the control panel.*

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ siteUrl }}css/file.css" />
```

Try using this method
if you want to use this on a multilingual Craft site. If you have multiple locales configured, siteUrl will be set to each locale's site URL, which might point to different folders. You can avoid this by setting a custom variable (eg. baseUrl) in your general.php file:

```
'environmentVariables' => array(
'baseUrl'  => 'http://example.dev/',)
```

and then use the absolute URL like so: